# Is mathematikalpha a reliable source for mathematical vocabulary?

Tags: mathematics, dictionary

I am looking for a list of the mathematical terms used by Newton, Euler, Gauss, etc. in their writings. The only thing I found online are those two files by Steffen Polster on <mathematikalpha.de>. How reliable are they?

- [Latein – Deutsch – Fachwörterbuch der Mathematik](https://mathematikalpha.de/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/fw_lat.pdf)
- [Deutsch - Latein – Fachwörterbuch der Mathematik](https://mathematikalpha.de/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/fword_late2.pdf)

Comment: Short look: Gleichung = equatio; Gleichungen = aequationes; gliedern = formam; Größe = magnitudine; Größe = parilitas … *uhhhh*